# Why can't my HTML code be displayed on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I made formulas with div and span, which contain some special symbols, but why can't they be displayed on the same line. I want them to show up like this -->[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2LhY.png)], But they are displayed line by line.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLTHe.png)]

Please tell me what I am doing wrong!

```html
<p>
  <sub>n</sub>C<sub>r</sub> =
  <div class="top"><sub>n</sub>P<sub>r</sub></div>
  <div> &nbsp; r!</div> =
  <div class="top">n!</div>
  <div> &nbsp; r!(n-r)!</div>
</p>

<br>

<p>
  <span>&#8747;</span>
  <div class="top">tan x</div>
  <div>sec<sup>4</sup>x</div> dx =
  <span>&#8747;</span>
  <div class="top">tan xsec x</div>
  <div>sec<sup>5</sup>x</div> dx

</p>
```

Comment: https://validator.nu/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML

Comment: Thanks guys, I will watch the platfrom you provide me!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currenly you are not using `float:left` or not using `display:flex` css to make element in one line.

Try below code. You will get expected result.

```html
<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;text-align: center;">
    <div style="margin-right: 10px">
        <sub>n</sub>C<sub>r</sub> =
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right: 10px">
        <div class = "top"><sub>n</sub>P<sub>r</sub></div>
        <hr>
        <div> &nbsp;  r!</div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right: 10px">=</div>
    <div>
        <div class = "top">n!</div>
        <hr>
        <div> &nbsp;  r!(n-r)!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They won't get the expected result in a screen reader. It will be unintelligible. This really calls for MathML.